# GetDirectoryContents method doesn't show files over 28MB

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, fileprovider

I'm currently trying to display files we've got in a directory. For this I'm using the IFileProvider / ContentRootFileProvider with it's method GetDirectoryContents(string path). It works like a charm on my local maschine with IIS in Visual Studio, but not on Azure. If I execute it locally, it shows every file with its details. But as soon as I try to run it on Azure, I only get files which are < 28MB. After googling a bit I tried editing the web.config on Azure and including the web.config into my project. Sadly both cases didn't work and I still just got files which were smaller than 28MB.

My edit to the web.config:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <!--400 MByte-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="419430400" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

***The code provided by Krishg's is valid and recommended.***

The solution I provided (file classification) sometimes ignores large files. This phenomenon is very strange.

```
new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExclusionFilters.None);
```

**PRIVIOUS**

I read your description carefully and tested it myself. This question is very interesting.

I tried to create a webapp and choose the `linux` platform, everything is normal. (**If you can, please choose this plan to deploy your program**).

Created under the `windows` platform, under the folder to be traversed, if it contains `picture files` (formats: `jpg`, `gif`, `png`), `.csproj` files, then files over 28M cannot be recognized.

I use kudu to upload large files. When it is less than a certain value, it can be seen. After uploading, it disappears, which is very strange.

**Solutions and suggestions:**

*1. Use linux platform to redeploy webapp*

*2. Classify files in the project. Assign to the corresponding folder when traversing.*

```
var contents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("/zip");
```

[image]

Test Result.

[image]

[image]

*3. You can raise a support ticket on portal and get the official answer. If it is really a bug, after you submit the question, the official will handle it and help the webapp to improve it.*

Comment: Sadly using linux is no option, since our subscription doesn't include it. Did I unterstand correctly, that you propose to create different folders for different types of files (2.)? Since I just have one folder which I need to go through (it has a lot of big .json files in it and I can't change anything), (2.) doesn't seem to be an option. That it, of course, if I understood you correctly.

I'll test everything tomorrow and will raise a support ticket if it doesn't play out. Thanks for the help! As for now, I'll mark your answer as accepted. :)

Comment: If you declare PhysicalFileProvider by passing ExclusionFilters.None param in constructor `new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExclusionFilters.None);`, it works fine :)

Comment: @krishg  Krishg is right, but there are many ways to read and traverse files. At present, the problem of op is a general and conventional writing method, and this problem will be encountered. In theory, the local test should be consistent with azure.

Comment: @0x41 You can choose any way to solve your problem. Whichever modifies the least, you take which approach.